# Get intersection from n number of list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, intersection

```
List x=new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>;
x.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("1","2","3","4")));
x.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("3","4")));
x.add(new ArrayList(Arrays.asList("4","5")));
```

Need to find intersection of all the list inside the list. Cant do manually as number of list inside the list varies.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

Can try:

```
List<String> result = (ArrayList<String>) x.get(0);
for (int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++) {
    result.retainAll((ArrayList<String>) x.get(i));
}
return result;
```